# Установка Windows 8 на Asus x555LB

Tags: windows, железо, драйвер, asus

При попытке установки windows на чистый HDD (без разметки) установщик требует драйвера на контроллер дисков (пробовал всю линейку с 7 по 10 ).  Возникает сообщение о необходимости драйвера, а в случае успешной установки отсутсвуют драйвера для USB контроллера.

Ноутбук `Asus x555LB`. 2 дня активного поиска в гугле к успеху не привели. Даже при наличии драйверов на контроллер диск не виден. В настройках BIOS стоит режим [CSM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_System). У кого какие варианты?

Comment: Вопрос, конечно, не по теме, но такие вопросы вроде не закрываются как "не о теме"?

Comment: Какое железо? Intel же кремний выпускает!

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробывать. А про вопрос не по теме, согласен, но это просто крик души))

Comment: Прошли те времена когда интел только камни делал))они еще и наборы мискросхем выпускают))

Comment: @Yurii Manziuk, спасибо. Помагло.

Comment: @Yurii Manziuk, оформи тогда как ответ, раз помогло. Чтобы потом не вчитываться в мелкий шрифт.

Comment: @donRumata ок. сейчас сделаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во всем виноват биос. попробуйте обновить, что ли. 
по крайней мере - почти всех это лечит от такой болезни

Comment: Да помогло. Спасибо)